# How would I produce JUnit test report for groovy tests, suitable for consumption by Jenkins/Hudson?

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, junit, hudson, jenkins

I've written several XMLUnit tests (that fit in to the JUnit framework) in groovy and can execute them easily on the command line as per the [groovy doco](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Using+JUnit+4+with+Groovy) but I don't quite understand what else I've got to do for it to produce the xml output that is needed by Jenkins/Hudson (or other) to display the pass/fail results (like [this](http://www.peterfranza.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/09/hudson_proj.png)) and detailed report of the errors etc (like [this](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/download/attachments/42467572/junit-attachments.png?version=1&modificationDate=1259357886000)). (apologies to image owners)

Currently, my kickoff script is this:

```
def allSuite = new TestSuite('The XSL Tests')

//looking in package xsltests.rail.*
allSuite.addTest(AllTestSuite.suite("xsltests/rail", "*Tests.groovy")) 

junit.textui.TestRunner.run(allSuite)
```

and this produces something like this:

```
Running all XSL Tests...
....
Time: 4.141

OK (4 tests)
```

How can I make this create a JUnit test report xml file suitable to be read by Jenkins/Hudson?

Do I need to kick off the tests with a different JUnit runner?

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4868586/1915) answer but would like to avoid having to write my own test report output.

Comment: Are you using some testing frameworks? What are you using to build the project?

Comment: Is there any aversion to using a build tool like Gradle/Maven/Ant?

Comment: @Eric This is a side project and was looking to get something up and running quickly. However, I may go down the path of learning and using Gradle as it is in my sphere of "things to learn".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a little hackage I have taken Eric Wendelin's suggestion and gone with Gradle.

To do this I have moved my groovy unit tests into the requisite directory structure src/test/groovy/, with the supporting resources (input and expected output XML files) going into the /src/test/resources/ directory.

All required libraries have been configured in the build.gradle file, as described (in its entirety) here:

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'

    groovy module('org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:1.8.2') {
        dependency('asm:asm:3.3.1')
        dependency('antlr:antlr:2.7.7')
        dependency('xmlunit:xmlunit:1.3')
        dependency('xalan:serializer:2.7.1')
        dependency('xalan:xalan:2.7.1')
        dependency('org.bluestemsoftware.open.maven.tparty:xerces-impl:2.9.0')
        dependency('xml-apis:xml-apis:2.0.2')
    }
}

test {
    jvmArgs '-Xms64m', '-Xmx512m', '-XX:MaxPermSize=128m'

    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true //not sure about this one, was in official user guide

    outputs.upToDateWhen { false } //makes it run every time even when Gradle thinks it is "Up-To-Date"
}
```

This applies the Groovy plugin, sets up to use maven to grab the specified dependencies and then adds some extra values to the built-in "test" task.

One extra thing in there is the last line which makes Gradle run all of my tests every time and not just the ones it thinks are new/changed, this makes Jenkins play nicely.

I also created a gradle.properties file to get through the corporate proxy/firewall etc:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=10.xxx.xxx.xxx
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.http.proxyUser=username
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=passwd
```

With this, I've created a 'free-style' project in Jenkins that polls our Mercurial repo periodically and whenever anyone commits an updated XSL to the repo all the tests will be run.

One of my original goals was being able to produce the standard Jenkins/Hudson pass/fail graphics and the JUnit reports, which is a success: [Pass/Fail](http://dands.ws/images/stackoverflow/xsltests_test_result_trend.png) with [JUnit Reports](http://dands.ws/images/stackoverflow/xsltests_test_result.png).

I hope this helps someone else with similar requirements.

Answer (score 2):

I find the fastest way to bootstrap this stuff is with [Gradle](http://gradle.org):

```
# build.gradle
apply plugin: 'groovy'

task initProjectStructure () << {
    project.sourceSets.all*.allSource.sourceTrees.srcDirs.flatten().each { dir ->
        dir.mkdirs()
    }
}
```

Then run `gradle initProjectStructure` and move your source into `src/main/groovy` and tests to `test/main/groovy`.

It seems like a lot (really it's <5 minutes of work), but you get lots of stuff for free. Now you can run `gradle test` and it'll run your tests and produce JUnit XML you can use in `build/test-reports` in your project directory.

Comment: Thanks for the little push to use Gradle. Whilst my answer (clearly) solved my issue, the 50pt bounty is yours.

Comment: Thanks :) - I think you'll love Gradle.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're asking for the purposes of exposing the report to Jenkins/Hudson, I'm assuming you have a Maven/Ant/etc build that you're able to run.  If that's true, the solution is simple.

First of all, there's practically no difference between Groovy and Java JUnit tests.  So, all you need to do is add the Ant/Maven junit task/plugin to your build and have it execute your Groovy junit tests (just as you'd do if they were written in Java).  That execution will create test reports.  From there, you can simply configure your Hudson/Jenkins build to look at the directory where the test reports get created during the build process.

Comment: No I'm not using build framework like Maven or Ant, it is merely a collection of unit tests. There is no build, only a series of tests with the hope to have a pass/fail tally for each time it is initiated.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own custom [RunListener](http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/runner/notification/RunListener.html) (or [SuiteRunListener](http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/test/junit4/listener/SuiteRunListener.html)). It still requires you to write some code, but it's much cleaner than the script you've provided a link to. If you'd like, I can send you the code for a JUnit reporter I've written in JavaScript for [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/) and you can 'translate' it into Groovy.