# Generate Junit Results in Jenkins from Groovy Script

Tags: groovy, jenkins, junit

How can you get a jenkins groovy script to produce a junit xml results file? I'm doing this purely for the purpose of generating junit results with a specific number of passed/failed and skipped test cases. I need this so that I have a set of test data to test against for another application. This other app goes out to various jenkins jobs and analyzes the junit results from the job's json output. I want to point my functional tests at this jenkins job for testing. (I can't use my real continuous integration jobs because that wouldn't be deterministic).

I've got a basic groovy test case like what's below. It runs but doesn't produce junit output. I didn't expect it to, but I'm also not sure how to get it to generate one.

```
class BunchOfTests extends GroovyTestCase {
 void testOne(){}
 void testTwo(){fail()}
}
```

I also played around with writing code that prints the junit results xml but it's getting lengthy and quite ugly. I've seen the threads on here about what the junit results xsd looks like but I'm thinking there's got to be an easier route to generating some results without needing a pre-made results file. 10 results or so ought to be enough for what I need.

Comment: Are you using a build tool? Gradle?

Comment: For this I wasn't.  I was trying to get away with just writing code in the groovy script build step field. Are there Gradle dependencies I could maybe @Grab that could work maybe? I'm open to using Gradle if I can confine it to the groovy script build step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally unit testcases in groovy has to be written as below

```
import groovy.util.GroovyTestCase

class sampleTest extends GroovyTestCase {

assertEquals(true, val);
}
```

Incase you want only Junit reporting in groovy.

[How would I produce JUnit test report for groovy tests, suitable for consumption by Jenkins/Hudson?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9312663/how-would-i-produce-junit-test-report-for-groovy-tests-suitable-for-consumption?rq=1)

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer because the link to the other Question contains a solution that explains pretty clearly how to do this with Gradle. Thanks.